# How to get std class object array which is having @ in the variable?

Tags: php, json, stdclass

How to get "size" value from this :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Hoa] => stdClass Object
        (
            [@size] => 4
            [customerSessionId] => 0AlAA82E-A0F5-AB91-3612-E3DE286965FC
            [hotelId] => 327929
```

If this is all in $result then I can fetch as $result->Hoa;
But how to get size ?
i tried like this $result-?Hoa->size;
can any one plz tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To access the `@size` property, you will need to use curly braces like this:

```
$result->Hoa->{"@size"};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be, `$result->Hoa->{"@size"}`?

Comment: I think it would if his dump showed it like `["@size"] => 4` instead of the way it does, although that customerSessionId definitely looks like it should be a string but didn't dump with quotes so who knows. Try both.

Comment: Interesting. Learn something new everyday!

Comment: +1 I've actually run into this before, not thinking to access the property in this way. :)